# Form validation and AJAX form submit using jQuery in CodeIgniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

when i submit form error show perfectly but when i submit again data enter in database but else condition not working i want to hide the form and show succes message

1st time response comes if password length less than 6

password must be greater than 6

2nd time response empty else condition should work but it cann't i want to hide the form if data enter successfully

```
<div class="modal-body">
 <div id="successResults"></div>
    <form method="" action="" class="form-horizontal signup-hide" role="form" id="signup-form">
        <div id="ajaxResults"></div>
           <input type="text" class="model-signup-fields"
                    name="first_name"  value="<?php echo $this->input->post('first_name');?>">  
           <input type="email" class="model-signup-fields" name="email"   value="<?php echo $this->input->post('email');?>">
          <input type="password" class="model-signup-fields" name="password"   value="<?php echo $this->input->post('password');?>">
           <input type="password" class="model-signup-fields" name="confirm_password"   value="">
                    <br>
          <input type="submit" name="remove" id="this_signup" class="claim btn btn-info model-signup "  onclick="" value="signup"  />
</form>
</div>
```

**controller**

```
       public function register() {
    $data['title'] = 'Register';
    $this->load->model('auth_model');

    if (count($_POST)) {
        $this->load->helper('security');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First name', 'trim|required');
        // $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm_password', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|min_length[6]|matches[password]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            // $data['notif']['message'] = validation_errors();
            // $data['notif']['type'] = 'danger';
             $status = validation_errors();
             if ( $this->input->is_ajax_request() ) {
                echo json_encode($status);

            }
        } 
        else {
            // $data['notif'] = $this->auth_model->register();

            $success_reg = $this->auth_model->register();



        }
    }

    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {    
        redirect(base_url('dashboard'));
        exit;
    }

    $this->load->view('includes/header', $data);

    $this->load->view('home/index');
    $this->load->view('includes/footer');
}
```

**script**

```
   $(function()
   {
      $('.model-signup').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      var form = $("#signup-form").serialize();

           $("#this_signup").css({"background-image":"url(<?PHP echo 
           base_url(); ?
            >assets/images/loading1.gif)",
           "background-repeat": "no-repeat",
           "background-position": "10% 50%"});
       $.ajax({
        url:"<?PHP echo base_url(); ?>auth/register",
        type:"POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data:form,
        success: function(response) {

            alert(response);

            var result2 = response;
            console.log(result2);

            if(result2)
            {   
                    alert("if");
                 $('#ajaxResults').addClass('alert alert-danger').html(result2);
                $("#this_signup").css({"background-image":"",
                    "background-repeat": "",
                    "background-position": ""});
            }
            if(response == ''){
                alert("else");
                $("#this_signup").css({"background-image":"",
                "background-repeat": "",
                "background-position": ""});
            $(".signup-hide").hide();
            $('#successResults').addClass('alert alert-success').html('You successfully register now you can login');
            }
            response='';


       }
        });
     });
 });
```

Comment: Please clarify - your question is unclear.  Please break it down with specific steps / conditions so we can track what you are saying is / is not happening as it should.

Comment: first time i submit the form error show this field is require etc but  2nd time when data enter in database than else condition work in the script but it cannot work

Comment: why can't it work? if data is entered properly than the script in the else should execute

Comment: that is my point why else condition not working

Answer (score 0):

Firstly to answer your question: After the form passes the rules, nothing happens ( the perspective of Ajax request) you serve an empty page with a status code 200. Echo an "okay" instead of nothing and compare if the response is(====) "okay".

Additional: It's not a right approach to redirect an ajax request. Echo an "alreay_logged_in" as status code which will be understood by Ajax. After that, you can redirect the user to the dashboard.

Comment: $success_reg = $this->auth_model->register();   $success_reg = 1  i add $success_reg equal 1 but in response the response 1 not comes response show empty

Comment: Do you also echo the $success_reg variable in the else statement?